# Ettercap JavaScript injection

Tags: javascript, injection, arp-spoofing

I am trying to remake an app like zANTI, but for other platforms.

I was wondering if I could use Ettercap (or something like it) to inject JavaScript into a targets web browser.

Comment: Define "or something" and "target". Using Ettercap to inject JS is akin to using a sledgehammer to insert nails.

Comment: Can you use ettercap to inject JavaScript? No. ettercap can be used in combination with other tools and techniques to accomplish this but by itself no. By target I'm assuming you mean when a user tries to retrieve a webpage and you inject JavaScript into that and send it back?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what Ettercap does. What you want is a proxy that rewrites requests.

Comment: I found a tool called Bettercap, which does this. I was trying to make filters that would replace `</head>` with `</head<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>`. But Bettercap has inbuilt functions for this.

Comment: @schroeder, what OP wants can and frequently is done using ettercap.

Comment: @leaustinwile example? I'm aware of packet editing, but not multi-packet data manipulation. You tend to need a proxy added on to ettercap for that

Comment: https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/ettercapfilter

The poster uses it to manipulate HTTP traffic in transit to inject images using ettercap filters. This could easily be adapted to inject malicious javascript code.